# Best Practice: Detecting electron shell

Tags: electron

I am loading a remote site in my electron app. I want to add some custom CSS when I am in the electron shell. I have noticed that the name from my package.json appears in the UserAgent. I know that I can do the following:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MyApp') >= 0) document.body.classList.add('electronified');
```

I am wondering if that is the best way to do that? Or if I should do it from the main process. What are you thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should instead attempt to look at `process.versions.electron`.

```
if (process && process.versions && process.versions.electron) {
    document.body.classList.add('electronified');
}
```

This is assuming you're not running your app inside of a `<webview>` of course.